# Transfer ether from one payable contract to another not working

Tags: solidity, ether, remix

Scenario:

I have users who will initiate booking for one product with `x` price. This contract will create a wallet contract between that user and the product so that he can return/cancel the booking at any time and get the refund or succeed.

Code:

User talks via contract `EthBooking`

```
contract EthBooking {
    function addBooking(uint listingId) public payable returns(uint bookingId) {
    bookingId =  BookingLibrary.book(ethDB, listingId, msg.sender, msg.value);

    //Send money to the contract
    return bookingId;
}
}
```

Booking Library code:

```
library BookingLibrary {

function book(address db, uint listingId, address sender, uint value) 
        internal returns (uint bookingId) 
{
    var cost = ListingLibrary.getCost(db,listingId);
        //Create Contract wallet
        EthWallet wallet = new EthWallet();
        //Send money to the contract
        wallet.receiveFunds.value(cost);
    return bookingId;
}
```

EthWallet Code:

```
contract EthWallet is Mortal {

function ethWallet() {
}

function receiveFunds() payable {

}

function sendFunds(address receiver, uint amount) {
    receiver.transfer(amount);
}
```

}

**PROBLEM**

The ethers sent is held in contract `EthBooking` and is not transferred to `EthWallet` as expected with code `wallet.receiveFunds.value(cost);` .

Please guide me about if the chosen approach is right and also why the ethers are not transferred to the destination. 
PS: The code is shortened with removal of irrelevant parts to avoid confusion

Comment: Why is sendFunds() payable?

Comment: Aw! May be a spill over from my trial and errors @MSwezey . Thanks for noticing. Removing it right away.

Answer (score 3):

I mocked this up in Truffle.

Using your way:

```
wallet.receiveFunds.value(cost);
```

Resulted in failure:

```
[ Instantiate Contract ]
    √ should instantiate the pact correctly
Wallet address: 0xa830ec357b950fde26d220b0f256b6d47529bdbd
Amount sent in wei: 3000000000000000000
Balance in eth wallet: 0
    (failed) 1) should transfer funds using library
```

Using this method:

```
wallet.receiveFunds.value(cost)();
```

Resulted in success:

```
[ Instantiate Contract ]
    √ should instantiate the pact correctly
Wallet address: 0xcc9fa65469197707e06eb16c2b01b9a62ddea75f
Amount sent in wei: 3000000000000000000
Balance in eth wallet: 3000000000000000000
    √ should transfer funds using library (410ms)
```

Others that worked:

```
wallet.send(cost);  // made a fallback function in EthWallet for this
wallet.transfer(cost);    // same as above, fallback function
address(wallet).call.value(cost)();  // fallback again
```

See `Sending and Receiving Ether` @ http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html?highlight=send%20transfer

Other Notes:
Your constructor should be exactly the same.
Not ethWallet but EthWallet.

Comment: why do i have `Error: Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of....` on `truffle test`

Answer (score 0):

Missing function call at the end:

```
wallet.receiveFunds.value(cost)();
```

Comment: I have tried tis and unfortunately the results are the same

Comment: There must be something else. Did you check if `cost > 0`?

Comment: yes I debug and I see the cost as `22000000000000000000` which is right.

Comment: There has be to something else with the code, I made some tests and value transfer happens successfully. I noticed there is a function named  `ethWallet` in your code. Is it meant to be a constructor? If so, you should name it `EthWallet` otherwise it won't work.